# java rest service consume multiple requests

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jakarta-ee

I have developed java Rest Service for processing Client Request

Client can post data to my  Rest Service Continuosly(Multiple requests)

My Rest Service has to Consume Client request and run update query in database and send an acknowledgement success or failure to the client

Could any one, how to process multiple requests inside my Rest Service method and send them response.

Comment: I think servlet container handles multiple request.

Comment: where you have deployed you REST service ? meaning on some server ? if yes the server will take care of this thing

Comment: I have deployed into Tomcat Server

Comment: then your server will put multiple requests in a queue no other thing specially need to do